# Simple if/else click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to add if else statement to below function.

The else statement will contain the following code so that `color_update` not only will be hidden but at the same time disabled when the button is not clicked.

```
$("#color_update").prop('disabled', true);
```

This is the code function:

**JS**

```
function open(elem) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        elem[0].dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        elem[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#update').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $('#color_update').addClass("show").focus();
        open( $('#color_update') ); 
        $("#color").prop('disabled', true);

    });
```

**CSS**

```
#color_update {
display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="color">
      <option value="Red">Red</option>
      <option value="Green">Green</option>
      <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" id="update" value="Update" />

    <select id="color_update">
      <option value="Red">Black</option>
      <option value="Green">Purple</option>
      <option value="Blue">White</option>
    </select>
```

Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want? `color_update` to be disabled initially? and How `open` function is relevant with the problem?

Comment: When does `open()` get called? currently no where in snippet??

Comment: I want to add if else statement to the `$('#update').click(function(event){` . The `color_update` is disabled from the start and only enabled when update button is clicked @Satpal

Comment: @Mint, can you elaborate. Please clearly mention what happens in both the `if` and `else` condition

Comment: When the `update` button is clicked, the `if` condition will disable the `color` and the `else` will be disabled the `color_update` . I understand that the `open()` function hide and show  the `color_update` . I want the `color_update` not only be hidden but at the same time disable. @Mayank Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understand, you want to disable/enbable one of the two select elements on the click of the button.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qen9mj7c/6/) for the same

Essentially we can use the `disabled` property of either of the select element as the deciding factor

```
    $("#color_update").prop('disabled', true); // Disable the select box initially
    $("#color_update").hide(); // Also hide it

    $('#update').click(function() {
      if ($('#color_update').prop('disabled') == true) { // We check the 'disabled' property to determine our next step

        // The button is now disabled, we need to enable it and hide the #color select 
        $("#color_update").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#color").prop('disabled', true);

        // We can now show and hide the respective select elements
        $("#color_update").show();
        $("#color").hide();
      } else { // We can now handle the other case
        $("#color_update").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#color").prop('disabled', false);

        $("#color_update").hide();
        $("#color").show();
      }
    });
```

Do let me know if you need something else

EDIT: Updated the jsFiddle link

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you @MayankRaj

Comment: @Mint, happy to help. Keep on hacking :)